# how to pass data from activity to java class in android

Tags: android-studio, intentservice

i want to pass some data from activity to a java class  i use intent to pass data  from activity to a java class .

// Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workspace);


    worklink = findViewById(R.id.workspace);
    button = findViewById(R.id.continu);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String work_link = worklink.getText().toString().trim();
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myKey", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("value", work_link);
            editor.apply();
            Intent intent = new Intent(workspace.this,BaseURL.class);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

// java class

```
import android.content.Intent;

public class BaseURL {

    String value = getIntent.getExtra("worklink");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Global class and create getter setter then set the data you want to pass

```
    public class GlobalData {
public static String status;
public static int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public static void setStatus(String status) {
    GlobalData.status = status;
}
}
```